# Cannot get if statement to display bonus amount if sales are greater than certain amount - JAVA

Tags: java

Okay, so here is the thing I'm stuck on. The code compiles. It prompts the user to enter in their sales. If the sales are over $3000 or equal to it, the program should print out a bonus of $100. I cannot see why it won't print that out when I type in 3000 + when prompted. Can someone help me out? Thanks to anyone who can. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Commission
{
        static Scanner keyboard;     // all methods will see it
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

       double basePay = 500;
       double commission = 0.10;
       float sales; // A sales amount entered by the user.

        sales = 335;

        commission = sales * 0.10;

       String input; // To hold the user's input

      // Create a scanner object for keyboard input.
       keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter your total sales for this month: ");
      input = keyboard.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Your Pay For This Month: ");
      System.out.println("Base Pay:$500.00 ");

         if (sales > 3000)
         System.out.println("BONUS for exceeding 3000 in sales: 100 ");


      System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: You initialize sales as 335 and you expect it to be strictly superior than 3000.

Comment: You haven't set `sales` to the value that the user typed in.  It stays at 335 throughout this program.

Comment: Correct. Either replace input with sales, or use input as your variable in your if statement.

Comment: By the way, ***never*** use floating point to represent money. You should either use `int` or `long` to represent a whole number of cents, or `BigDecimal` to represent a decimal value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only assign `sales` once, when the program asks for sales input, re-assign the `sales` variable to that amount. Try this after where you create the `Scanner` object:

```
System.out.println("Enter your total sales for this month: ");
sales = keyboard.nextInt();
```

That should read your inputted number the way you want it. You also may want to change the `sales` type from `float` to `int` for more precision, as floating point decimals can lose accuracy. Or you can just change `keyboard.nextInt()` to `keyboard.nextFloat()`

Another programming tip: Remember to close any I/O utilites you use, in this case, `Scanner`. Just call `keyboard.close();` after you have done using it.

Comment: Using `nextInt()` to read a variable of type `float` seems an odd thing to do.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem. Also, thank you for your tip. You're a saint.